# Is Pic a functor?

Tags: field-theory, category-theory

Let $K$ be a field. Is $Pic$ a functor from the category of fields and field homomorphisms to the category of groups and group homomorphisms, where $Pic(K)$ is the Picard group of $K$?

Comment: What is your definition of Pic? Is the picard group of a field not always trivial?

Answer (score 5):

The Picard group [is even a (contravariant) functor on the category of schemes **Sch**](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B9K). Since the category of commutative rings and ring homomorphisms **CRng** is a subcategory of $\mathbf{Sch}^\mathrm{op}$, and **Fld** is a subcategory of that, the yes, *Pic* is a (covariant) functor on **Fld**.

However, that is overkill; I mention it only to satisfy other related queries you might have.

As mentioned in the comments, the [Picard group of a UFD](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AFW) is trivial. Since fields are UFDs, as a functor on **Fld**, *Pic* is isomorphic to the constant functor that assigns to every field $K$ the zero group, and to every field morphism the identity map on the zero group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments @Hurkyl @MCT! In fact I haven't really studied about Picard groups in great detail though my professor mentioned it as a generalization of the ideal class group of a number field. So I thought that the Picard group of a field is not trivial since ideal class groups is not always trivial. So thank you for your comments since it shed a really great amount of light. :)

Comment: @HabagatMaliksi: A common abuse of language in algebraic number theory is, given a ring-theoretic property of the *ring of integers* of the number field, to call it a property of the number field itself. The ideal class group of a number field is trivial; but you mean the phrase to *actually* refer to the ideal class group of the ring of integers.